# Speed up Python cKDTree

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, vectorization, nearest-neighbor

I currently have a function that I created that connects the blue dots with its (at maximum) 3 nearest neighbors within a pixel range of 55. The vertices_xy_list is an extremely large list or points (nested list) of about 5000-10000 pairs.

Example of `vertices_xy_list`:

```
[[3673.3333333333335, 2483.3333333333335],
 [3718.6666666666665, 2489.0],
 [3797.6666666666665, 2463.0],
 [3750.3333333333335, 2456.6666666666665],...]
```

I currently have written this `calculate_draw_vertice_lines()` function that uses a CKDTree inside of a While loop to find all points within 55 pixels and then connect them each with a green line.

It can be seen that this would become exponentially slower as the list gets longer. Is there any method to speed up this function significantly? Such as vectorizing operations?

```
def calculate_draw_vertice_lines():

    global vertices_xy_list
    global cell_wall_lengths
    global list_of_lines_references

    index = 0

    while True:

        if (len(vertices_xy_list) == 1):

            break

        point_tree = spatial.cKDTree(vertices_xy_list)

        index_of_closest_points = point_tree.query_ball_point(vertices_xy_list[index], 55)

        index_of_closest_points.remove(index)

        for stuff in index_of_closest_points:

            list_of_lines_references.append(plt.plot([vertices_xy_list[index][0],vertices_xy_list[stuff][0]] , [vertices_xy_list[index][1],vertices_xy_list[stuff][1]], color = 'green'))

            wall_length = math.sqrt( (vertices_xy_list[index][0] - vertices_xy_list[stuff][0])**2 + (vertices_xy_list[index][1] - vertices_xy_list[stuff][1])**2 )

            cell_wall_lengths.append(wall_length)

        del vertices_xy_list[index]

    fig.canvas.draw()
```

[image]

Comment: Where do you define `index`?

Comment: Also, why cannot you move `point_tree = spatial.cKDTree(vertices_xy_list)` outside of the loop?

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko I modify the vertices_xy_list every cycle by deleting the value at each index that is drawn, this way I do not have any repeated lines being drawn or used. Essentially, my vertices_xy_list gets smaller and smaller until it has only 1 point left in which it breaks.

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko index is set to 0, but it doesn't get incremented because I always start from the beginning of the vertices_xy_list[] since it deletes this point in this list after its been used.

Comment: Thanks @Kira. I added an answer. Let me know if my assumption about the blue lines is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the logic of selecting the green lines correctly, there is no need to create a KDTree at each iteration. For each pair (p1, p2) of blue points, the line should be drawn if and only if the following hold:

1. p1 is one of 3 closest neighbors of p2.
2. p2 is one of 3 closest neighbors of p1.
3. dist(p1, p2) < 55.

You can create the KDTree once and create a list of green lines efficiently. Here is part of the implementation that returns a list of pairs of indices for points between which the green lines need to be drawn. The runtime is about 0.5 seconds on my machine for 10,000 points.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import spatial


data = np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=(10_000, 2))

def get_green_lines(data):
    tree = spatial.cKDTree(data)
    # each key in g points to indices of 3 nearest blue points
    g = {i: set(tree.query(data[i,:], 4)[-1][1:]) for i in range(data.shape[0])}

    green_lines = list()
    for node, candidates in g.items():
        for node2 in candidates:
            if node2 < node:
                # avoid double-counting
                continue

            if node in g[node2] and spatial.distance.euclidean(data[node,:], data[node2,:]) < 55:
                green_lines.append((node, node2))

    return green_lines
```

You can proceed to plot green lines as follows:

```
green_lines = get_green_lines(data)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], s=1)
from matplotlib import collections as mc
lines = [[data[i], data[j]] for i, j in green_lines]
line_collection = mc.LineCollection(lines, color='green')
ax.add_collection(line_collection)
```

Example output:

[image]

Comment: I may be a little confused, since each green line is a connection between two blue points, how would you actually draw the green lines in in your current code? Since blue_lines is just a list of tuples with no reference to know how to connect lines.

Comment: I added a clarificaiton. Since you know that the indices in `green_lines` list returned from the `get_green_lines` function are the same as the indices in the `data` array, you can recover the list of coordinates associated with each line.

Comment: I was able to implement your function into my code however, there does not seem to be any speed up at all, maybe even a slow down. Does it perhaps have anything to do with fig.canvas.draw()?

Comment: Can you check how much time is spent on plotting vs. computing the set of lines? If the number of points is large it will take far longer to render than to find the required lines. Your main performance issue may be with matplotlib.

Comment: You are correct, adding the plt.scatter(), plt.plot(), and plt.show() portion of the code makes the script much much slower, It takes 5-10 minutes to actually display the matlibplot. Is there any work around for matlibplot's extremely slow plotting?

Comment: It appears that pyplot.collections can improve performance. I've updated the snippet, let me know if it works better.

Comment: LineCollection fixed it. Thank you for the help.